# How to get a bootstrap combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to accomplish designing a filter/search feature that allows the user to easily search through a list for an item. I was told that I could accomplish this by using a Bootstrap combo box, however I have not seen any that have the ability to show the user values as soon as they start typing. The only ones I have found online where you had to click a button to see a drop down of the values.

This is the code I tried using, it works but instead I would like it to drop down the list only when I click the search `input field`.  I am trying to make it without a button.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable List</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>  
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding this Javascritpt function, but it did not work.

**Snippet:**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myList").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: jQuery-UI  library contains a combobox that you can use https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ or use this bootstrap snippet  https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0Bn1j

Answer (score 0):

You can hide automatically by triggering the toggle function in the page load. And to show the list you can use the toggle function again in focus event and to hide it again you can use it on the focus out event

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myList").toggle();

        $("#myInput").on("focus", function() {
          $("#myList").toggle();
        });

        $("#myInput").on("focusout", function() {
         $("#myList").toggle();
       });

          $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {

            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myList li").filter(function() {
              $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
          });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however I am trying to select or choose the text that I need. Though when I trying clicking the text or pressing enter, because how it is setup, the window disappears. I believe it is from the "toggle".

Comment: I am trying to find a solution, please let me know if there is a simpler way to go about accomplishing this.